# JavaScript Getting values from 2 exclusive pages and printing the values on third using localstorage

Tags: local-storage

I am trying to take data from 2 pages, store it in `localstorage` and print it on the third. The problem is that on the third page the data from only `page 1` or either `page 2` gets printed.

**Page1.html**

```
function save() {
                if (html5_storage_support()) {
                    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
```

**Page2.html**

```
function save() {
                if (html5_storage_support()) {
                    var fathername = document.getElementById("fathername").value;
```

**PrintPage.html**

```
function set() {
        if (html5_storage_support()) {

            document.getElementById("firstname").value = 
localStorage.getItem('firstname');
            document.getElementById("fathername").value = 
localStorage.getItem('fathername');
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code from Page1.html and Page2.html that does the actual storing of the data to localStorage. PrintPage.html seems to be missing some context too.

Comment: I havent put the code that checks if the browser supports localstorage or not.. apart from that the entire code is just repeatition of what I have posted. The passing of values is working fine between page 1 and printpage and between page 2 and print page. But it just doesnt prints values from both the pages at once.

Comment: I'm still confused. 
The first code snippet gets the value of the HTML element with the ID "firstname" and puts it in a variable.
The second code snippet gets the value of the HTML element with the ID "fathername" and puts it in a variable.
The third code snippet gets items from localStorage that have not been set anywhere. Maybe provide some HTML code or set up an example is JSFiddle etc. to help explain your problem.

Comment: First name: <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
Father's Name: <input type="text" id="fathername"><br>

I have set the textfields for the fetched data. I just didn't put it up here thinking thats obvious, my bad, asking question for the first time out here..